# How to make a user be able to register if such a login already exists?

Tags: login, user-registration

And then to log in only by e-mail and password.

Comment: can you be more specific? By "such a login" do you mean the username? Usernames in WordPress are unique, but display names, nicknames, first, last, etc can all be configured on a per user basis and are not unique

Comment: yes, username. as I understand it, you can’t make the usernames the same, while you can make the username hidden for the user during registration, and set automatically, for example, based on the user’s email address, but there were other fields, such as first and last name. How can this be done, are there any code examples?

Comment: the other fields are not unique, you don't need to do anything for that, and WP already supports entering the email and password instead of the username out of the box, go to your site and try it now.

Answer (score 1):

First for the usernames, you already have the answer:

> you can’t make the usernames the same, while you can make the username hidden for the user during registration, and set automatically, for example, based on the user’s email address

Second for the other fields, they already work the way you want and are not unique. You could give every user the same first/last/display name, they are not unique.

> And then to log in only by e-mail and password.

**WordPress already has this out the box by default**, no changes are necessary, it already works.